# How to make org2blog work with Crayon Syntax Highlighter?

Tags: wordpress, emacs, org-mode

I use org2blog/wp to post my articles to wordpress. I installed the plugin [Crayon Syntax Highlighter](https://github.com/aramk/crayon-syntax-highlighter), but it failed to highlight my code block. 
I think there may be 2 reasons.

First problem, the tags.

Crayon checks the tags

```
<pre>

...(my code)

</pre>
```

but org2blog/wp outputs the code block's format as

```
[sourcecode]

...(my code)

[/sourcecode]
```

I don't know whether we can customize the code block's output format, I try to change the src of  function "org-wp-src-block". In [ox-wp.el](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog/blob/master/ox-wp.el),

```
...
(if (not sc)
        (org-html-src-block src-block contents info)
       ;;(format "[sourcecode language=\"%s\" title=\"%s\" %s]\n%s[/sourcecode]"
         (format "<pre class=\"lang:%s decode:true\" title =\"%s\"> %s\n%s</pre>" 
              (or (cdr (assoc lang langs-map)) lang "text")
              (or caption "")
              (or syntaxhl "")
              (org-export-format-code-default src-block info)))))
...
```

As show above, I replace `[sourcecode language=\"%s\" title=\"%s\" %s]\n%s[/sourcecode]` with `<pre class=\"lang:%s decode:true\" title =\"%s\"> %s\n%s</pre>`.

It fixed the first problem, that is, org2blog/wp now can outputs the code block's format like this:

```
<pre>
...(my code)
</pre>
```

But I still wonder if there is another elegant method to solve the tag problem.

Second problem, I will give an example.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC cpp
int a = 4;
cout << a;
#+END_SRC
```

Above is a code block in an org file, and I use org2blog/wp to post and public it to my blog.

```
<pre class="lang:cpp decode:true" title =""> 
int a = 4;
cout << a;
</pre>
```

Above is what the org2blog/wp outputs. Should it output like this?

```
<pre class="lang:cpp decode:true" title =""> 
int a = 4;
cout &lt;&lt; a;
</pre>
```

The org2blog/wp seems not escape some chars in src block, like '<','>'.

In another words, I want org2blog/wp to convert '<' to `'&lt;'` in code blocks. How to do that?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you are really trying to do. And consider providing links to "crayon syntax highlighter" and "org2blog".

Comment: Thanks! I have re-edit my question.